# Set PageView child page width or height after loading webview content

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-pageview

I have a screen with a PageView, PageView have 3 webView as childs, and pageView scrollDirection is Axis.vertical, the problem is each pageView child height is not adjust to the height of each webView height.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
return PageView(
  /// [PageView.scrollDirection] defaults to [Axis.horizontal].
  /// Use [Axis.vertical] to scroll vertically.
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  controller: controller,
  children: const <Widget>[
    createWebView("/book/page1.html"),
    createWebView("/book/page2.html"),
    createWebView("/book/page3.html"),
  ],
);
```

}

[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ybqRyp5.mp4)

How to set the height for each pageView child after load web content completed, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping each child in SizedBox with height set to MediaQuery.of(context).size.height?

Comment: Yes, I did. But the webview only have the contentHeight after content loaded. When I get the contentHeight and assign to height of the SizedBox which wrap webview, call setState to update the screen, but the PageView didnt resize the height of each child page.

Comment: @noname.cs have you found any solution for this?